# PGError: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, heroku

I'm getting the following PGError while ingesting Rails emails from Cloudmailin:

```
PGError: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xbb HINT: This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding". : INSERT INTO "comments" ("content") VALUES ('Reply with blah blah  ����������������������������������������������������� .....
```

So it seems pretty clear I have some invalid UTF8 characters getting into the email right? So I tried to clean that up but something is still Sneaking through. Here's what I have so far:

```
message_all_clean = params[:message]
Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', message_all_clean)
message_plain_clean = params[:plain]
Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', message_plain_clean)

@incoming_mail = IncomingMail.create(:message_all => Base64.encode64(message_all_clean), :message_plain => Base64.encode64(message_plain_clean))
```

Any ideas, thoughts or suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

When encountering this issue on Heroku, we converted to US-ASCII to sanitize incoming data appropriately (i.e. pasted from Word):

```
Iconv.conv("UTF-8//IGNORE", "US-ASCII", content)
```

With this, we had no more issues with character encoding.

Also, double check that there's no other fields that need the same conversion, as it could affect anything that's passing a block of text to the database.

Comment: Thanks but do I need to do something like CLEAN = Iconv.conv("UTF-8//IGNORE", "US-ASCII", content) or does Iconv convert the content var and I can just send content to the DB?

Comment: Ah, there I am not sure. In actual practice, I created an Iconv object (ic = Iconv.new("UTF-8//IGNORE", "US-ASCII")), and then used the iconv method: content = ic.iconv(content). Iconv.conv() seems to be a shorthand for that, but I preferred having a reusable object.

Comment: How to convert it into Ruby 1.9.3 where Iconv is deprecated?